# Disc brake equipped time trial bikes in grand tour

Tags: disc-brake, racing, tour-de-france

Why did team Deceuninck–Quick-Step ride disc brake equipped time trial bikes in a relatively flat course through Brussels in stage 2 of the 2019 Tour de France?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason is the 2020 Specialized Shiv provided by their sponsor is only produced in a disc version.

You can see an article about the bike here:
https://www.bikeradar.com/news/specialized-sworks-shiv-tt-disc/

Comment: Also just because it's a flat course, doesn't mean it's not technical. That particular TT had a number of sharp corners, in which the superior braking power of a disc brake bike would be an advantage, especially if the bike is aerodynamically faster with disc brakes than it would have been with rim brakes (as noted in the article). Better brakes = faster times.